# Access a file which is in diffrent project but in same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a xml file in a console app project after and writing data in it from a txt file and also i have a asp.net core mvc project in the same solution .I want to read xml data in asp.net core project but i cant access the file which is in diffrent project but in same solution.

```
public IActionResult List()
    {
        List<Models.Word> wordList = new List<Models.Word>();
  string xmlPath=@"~\\YCMobyDickChallenge\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\words.xml";
        //using (FileStream fs = new FileStream())
        using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlPath))
        {
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                switch (xmlReader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        if (xmlReader.Name != "words")
                        {
                            Models.Word word = new Models.Word();
                            word.text = xmlReader.GetAttribute("text");
                  word.count = Convert.ToInt32(xmlReader.GetAttribute("count"));
                            wordList.Add(word);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        wordList.Sort();
        return View(wordList);
    }
```

In this solution named like `YCMobyDickChallenge` i have two projects like `YCMobyDickChallenge` and `YCMobyDickWebApp` and im trying to access words.xml file which is in console app from web app. When i call this action it gives me an error like.

> "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   'C:\Users\cosku\source\repos\YCMobyDickChallenge\YCMobyDickWebApp\~\YCMobyDickChallenge\YCMobyDickChallenge\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\words.xml'.'"

Comment: I've solved it like
 string xmlPath=@"~\\YCMobyDickChallenge\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\words.xml";

to change
  string xmlPath =@"..\\YCMobyDickChallenge\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\words.xml";

Answer (score 0):

since you already found your answer, I will give you some comments on the code you present.

1. Why do you save your text files in the project folder? If you are creating files often you should consider creating separate folder outside your project folder. then save the output folder path in a string constant and use it across different projects.
   You can have a class containing all the constants you have like:

`public static constant string BatchOutputFolder = @"C:\BatchOutput\";`

```
var xmlPath = Constants.BatchOutputFolder + "words.xml";
```

2. when you are using the '@'sign to declare a path string you don't need double backslash '\'.